# Is it possible to have two load balancers attached to Azure VM scale set?

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

our app is hosted in Azure VM scale set and it has 80 and 8080 endpoints, 
80 must be public and 8080 must be private.

Obvious way to achieve this is to use one public and one private load balancer.

Is it possible in Azure VM scale set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this it is.
https://heranonazure.wordpress.com/2017/08/30/vmss-behind-both-internal-and-external-load-balancer/

However, I have attached my VMSS to 2 load balancers, 1 internal and 1 external. It does work just fine, but you do get a warning saying that 1 backend address pool has been removed....however I can still access resources via both load balancers. Whether this persists after any maintenance or scaling of the VMSS remains to be seen.

I would say on the Basic SKU LoadBalancer it is NOT supported even though you can get it to work to some degree.

The Standard load balancer may well be different, however that is still in preview.